# Attach Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) to Azure Container Registry (ACR) without being Subscription Owner

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-container-registry

I'm deploying AKS via ARM template and Azure DevOps pipeline and want to automate attachment to ACR

To do so I need to execute `az aks update --name $(clusterName) --resource-group $(rgName) --attach-acr $(containerRegistryName)`

..but that requires Owner on Subscription level and I don't want service principle to have it

Is there any workaround available?

Comment: Any more updates for the question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You only workaround would be to create a custom role that only allows to assign permissions to that specific resource. that would look like something like this:

```
$role = Get-AzureRmRoleDefinition "Virtual Machine Contributor"
$role.Id = $null
$role.Name = "xxx"
$role.Description = "yyy"
$role.Actions.Clear()
$role.Actions.Add("Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write")
$role.AssignableScopes.Clear()

$scope = "your azure container registry resourceId"
$role.AssignableScopes.Add($scope)
$def = New-AzureRmRoleDefinition -Role $role
```

maybe you need to add read permissions as well, due to how az cli is implemented, but in essence write should be enough